# how to submit dropdown form without submit button and without refresh

Tags: html

I need your help
I am using Onchange in a form to submit a dropdown data to the database, but something boring when i select the data the page get refreshed, so if i was down the page then after selecting the page takes me up again before i finish the next stage on my process.
So i need the help if anyone knows how can i do to stop that, that when i will select the dropdown data the page should remain without refresh it will be well and good!
I think Ajax does this but im not that much aware with AJAX
Here is my codes

```
<html>
<form action="" method="post" style="height:1px;">
<input name="key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<select name="Idadi"style="width:65px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="1" <?php if($Idadi=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option> 
<option value="2" <?php if($Idadi=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option> 
<option value="3" <?php if($Idadi=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option> 
<option value="4" <?php if($Idadi=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option> 
<option value="5" <?php if($Idadi=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option> 
</select>
</form>
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');
if(isset($_POST['key'])){ 
$idlogin=$_POST['key'];     
$idadi=$_POST['Idadi'];   
$idadiquery="update `itemreg` set `Idadi` = '$idadi' where `id` ='$idlogin'";
$idadiresult = mysql_query($idadiquery);
if($idadiresult){
echo ""; // print massage
}  
} 
?>
```

Comment: You're right. To do this without a refresh you will need to use AJAX. I recommend taking a look at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get started.

Comment: Rory, waiting for your help man